# Understanding the lifecycle of DataBinding

Tags: java, android, data-binding

My Activity:

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPlayerDetailsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)

    }
```

I'm trying to understand how the data binding process works, this is how I understand it:

- `private lateinit var binding: ActivityPlayerDetailsBinding`
  instantiates the `ViewDataBinding` object.
- `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
  R.layout.activity_player_details)` is in 2 parts:

  1. `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
     R.layout.activity_player_details)` sets the content view to the given layout
  2. It then returns the binding object to the `binding variable` (`binding = ...`) which can then be used to access views in the layout.

Is this an accurate way of describing how the code is working? I found the source code for `DataBindingUtil.java` hard to understand. Mostly because `setContentView()` is being called even though it appears to be assigned instead `binding = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_datails) do almost same thing to return binding object. Although `DataBindingUtils.setContentView` call `activity.setContentView` before returning.

Instead, I usually override `setContentView` to make sure assign binding object into variables and sets content to the given layout.

```
override fun setContentView(layoutResID: Int) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), layoutResID, null, false)
        super.setContentView(mBinding.root)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how `setContentView()` is being called in an assignment (`binding = ...`)

Comment: You means 'DatabindUtils.setContentView()`? if yes, they called activity.setContentVeiw() internally. you should check this [code](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.java#L292)